# Convert an IP string to a number and vice versa

Tags: python, django

How would I use python to convert an IP address that comes as a `str` to a decimal number and vice versa?

For example, for the IP `186.99.109.000 <type'str'>`, I would like to have a decimal or binary form that is easy to store in a database, and then retrieve it.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/

Comment: @PeterWood nowadays i just googled for it and the first result was this answer xD

Answer (score 112, accepted):

converting an IP string to long integer:

```
import socket, struct

def ip2long(ip):
    """
    Convert an IP string to long
    """
    packedIP = socket.inet_aton(ip)
    return struct.unpack("!L", packedIP)[0]
```

the other way around:

```
>>> socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L', 2130706433))
'127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: love this line from the python documentation `The form '!' is available for those poor souls who claim they can’t remember whether network byte order is big-endian or little-endian.`

Answer (score 64):

Here's a summary of all options as of 2017-06. All modules are either part of the standard library or can be installed via `pip install`.

### ipaddress module

Module ipaddress ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)) is part of the standard library since v3.3 but it's also available as an external module for python v2.6,v2.7.

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> int(ipaddress.ip_address('1.2.3.4'))
16909060
>>> str(ipaddress.ip_address(16909060))
'1.2.3.4'
>>> int(ipaddress.ip_address(u'1000:2000:3000:4000:5000:6000:7000:8000'))
21268296984521553528558659310639415296L
>>> str(ipaddress.ip_address(21268296984521553528558659310639415296L))
u'1000:2000:3000:4000:5000:6000:7000:8000'
```

### No module import (IPv4 only)

Nothing to import but works only for IPv4 and the code is longer than any other option.

```
>>> ipstr = '1.2.3.4'
>>> parts = ipstr.split('.')
>>> (int(parts[0]) << 24) + (int(parts[1]) << 16) + \
          (int(parts[2]) << 8) + int(parts[3])
16909060
>>> ipint = 16909060
>>> '.'.join([str(ipint >> (i << 3) & 0xFF)
          for i in range(4)[::-1]])
'1.2.3.4'
```

### Module netaddr

netaddr is an external module but is very stable and available since Python 2.5 ([doc](http://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/))

```
>>> import netaddr
>>> int(netaddr.IPAddress('1.2.3.4'))
16909060
>>> str(netaddr.IPAddress(16909060))
'1.2.3.4'
>>> int(netaddr.IPAddress(u'1000:2000:3000:4000:5000:6000:7000:8000'))
21268296984521553528558659310639415296L
>>> str(netaddr.IPAddress(21268296984521553528558659310639415296L))
'1000:2000:3000:4000:5000:6000:7000:8000'
```

### Modules socket and struct (ipv4 only)

Both modules are part of the standard library, the code is short, a bit cryptic and IPv4 only.

```
>>> import socket, struct
>>> ipstr = '1.2.3.4'
>>> struct.unpack("!L", socket.inet_aton(ipstr))[0]
16909060
>>> ipint=16909060
>>> socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L', ipint))
'1.2.3.4'
```

Comment: No need to use stuff like `2**16`, just use `<< 16` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip interestinglythere. I do like this notation (it reminds me of my first 6502 assembler programs).

Comment: User [brisebom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1697876) tried to post this comment as an answer: *"Here is a simple benchmark test for most of the examples in @ndemou's answer. If you are already using the `ipaddress` module for your addresses, the IP int is precalculated so it is the fastest method. Otherwise, socket/struct is the fastest method by a quite a lot. https://ideone.com/cZU9Ar"*

Comment: A kind soul did some benchmarks here https://ideone.com/cZU9Ar -- thanks to @brisebom and artjom-b for letting us know (I only repeat it here because the link in Artjom's comment got corrupted)

Comment: `str(ipaddress.ip_address(16909060))` is a simpler way to convert integer to string.

Answer (score 30):

Use class `IPAddress` in module `netaddr`.

ipv4 `str` -> `int`:

```
print int(netaddr.IPAddress('192.168.4.54'))
# OUTPUT: 3232236598
```

ipv4 `int` -> `str`:

```
print str(netaddr.IPAddress(3232236598))
# OUTPUT: 192.168.4.54
```

ipv6 `str` -> `int`:

```
print int(netaddr.IPAddress('2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329'))
# OUTPUT: 42540766411282592856904265327123268393
```

ipv6 `int` -> `str`:

```
print str(netaddr.IPAddress(42540766411282592856904265327123268393))
# OUTPUT: 2001:db8::ff00:42:8329
```

Comment: Very nice but putting the output before the input confuses me

Answer (score 7):

Since Python 3.3 there is the ipaddress module that does exactly this job among others: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html. Backports for Python 2.x are also available on PyPI.

Example usage:

```
import ipaddress

ip_in_int = int(ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.1.1'))
ip_in_hex = hex(ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.1.1'))
```

Comment: For the hex(ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.1.1')), got error. 'IPv4Address' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. Seems to use hex(int(...)). It is good to know the new ipaddress module.

Comment: Last line should be `ipaddress.ip_address(3232235777).__str__()`. This really returns `'192.168.1.1'` which is what the question asks for

Answer (score 6):

### Here's One Line Answers:

```
import socket, struct

def ip2long_1(ip):
    return struct.unpack("!L", socket.inet_aton(ip))[0]
```

---

```
def ip2long_2(ip):
    return long("".join(["{0:08b}".format(int(num)) for num in ip.split('.')]), 2)
```

---

```
def ip2long_3(ip):
    return long("".join(["{0:08b}".format(num) for num in map(int, ip.split('.'))]), 2)
```

---

### Execution Times:

ip2long_1 => 0.0527065660363234 ( The Best ) 
ip2long_2 => 0.577211893924598 
ip2long_3 => 0.5552745958088666

Answer (score 5):

One line solution without any module import:

```
ip2int = lambda ip: reduce(lambda a, b: (a << 8) + b, map(int, ip.split('.')), 0)
int2ip = lambda n: '.'.join([str(n >> (i << 3) & 0xFF) for i in range(0, 4)[::-1]])
```

Example:

```
In [3]: ip2int('121.248.220.85')
Out[3]: 2046352469

In [4]: int2ip(2046352469)
Out[4]: '121.248.220.85'
```

Answer (score 5):

Convert IP to integer :

```
python -c "print sum( [int(i)*2**(8*j) for  i,j in zip( '10.20.30.40'.split('.'), [3,2,1,0]) ] )"
```

Convert Interger to IP :

```
python -c "print '.'.join( [ str((169090600 >> 8*i) % 256)  for i in [3,2,1,0] ])"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def ip2Hex(ip = None):
    '''Returns IP in Int format from Octet form'''
    #verifyFormat(ip)
    digits=ip.split('.')
    numericIp=0
    count=0
    for num in reversed(digits):
        print "%d " % int(num)
        numericIp += int(num) * 256 **(count)
        count +=1
    print "Numeric IP:",numericIp
    print "Numeric IP Hex:",hex(numericIp)

ip2Hex('192.168.192.14')
ip2Hex('1.1.1.1')
ip2Hex('1.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one

```
def ipv4_to_int(ip):
    octets = ip.split('.')
    count = 0
    for i, octet in enumerate(octets):
        count += int(octet) << 8*(len(octets)-(i+1))
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `clean_ip` from the library [DataPrep](https://dataprep.ai/) if your IP addresses are in a DataFrame. Install DataPrep with `pip install dataprep`.

```py
from dataprep.clean import clean_ip
df = pd.DataFrame({"ip": ["186.99.109.000", "127.0.0.1", "1.2.3.4"]})
```

To convert to a decimal format, set the parameter `output_format` to `"integer"`:

```py
df2 = clean_ip(df, "ip", output_format="integer")
# print(df2)
               ip    ip_clean
0  186.99.109.000  3127078144
1       127.0.0.1  2130706433
2         1.2.3.4    16909060
```

To convert to a binary format, set the parameter `output_format` to `"binary"`:

```py
df2 = clean_ip(df, "ip", output_format="binary")
# print(df2)
               ip                          ip_clean
0  186.99.109.000  10111010011000110110110100000000
1       127.0.0.1  01111111000000000000000000000001
2         1.2.3.4  00000001000000100000001100000100
```

To convert back to IPv4, set the parameter `output_format` to `"compressed"`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"ip": [3127078144, 2130706433, 16909060]})
df2 = clean_ip(df, "ip", output_format="compressed")
# print(df2)
           ip      ip_clean
0  3127078144  186.99.109.0
1  2130706433     127.0.0.1
2    16909060       1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first convert the string that contains the IP address into a byte or a string of bytes and then start communicating.
According to the code below, your error will be resolved.
Make sure your code is working correctly overall.

```
string = '192.168.1.102'
new_string = bytearray(string,"ascii")
ip_receiver = new_string
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto(text.encode(), (ip_receiver, 5252))
```