# Regular expression matching for IP range in Ansible Playbooks for grouping

Tags: python, regex, ansible

I am trying to write a regular expression for a dynamic group in ansible-playbook for an sample ip range. 
if the address range is 172.30.0.(0 to 254).(0 to 254).  My regex is like 
172.30.[0-254].[0-254]. Is this correct ? Even though I have the hosts in the range, the tasks are being skipped and no groups are being formed.

tasks:
   - group_by: key=adda
     when: ansible_default_ipv4.network == '172.30.[0-254].[0-254]'

[image: grouping picture]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex: How to match IP address in RFC1918 private IPV4 address ranges (in Python)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674845/regex-how-to-match-ip-address-in-rfc1918-private-ipv4-address-ranges-in-python)

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image, in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the operator '**==**' then in python you are trying to find a matched string with the name '172.30.[0-254[.[0-254]'

In ansible you can use python expression like search or match.

So you need to type something like this:

```
when: ansible_default_ipv4.address | match("172.30.")
```

Did a test ansible playbook to verify it.

Answer (score 2):

If you compare networks, you shouldn't care about ranges!

```
tasks:
  - group_by: key=adda
    when: ansible_default_ipv4.network == '172.30.0.0'
```

This will (generally) match all hosts with IPs 172.30.0.1 - 172.30.255.255.

If you need to compare IP addresses, use [ipaddr](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html) filter:

```
tasks:
  - group_by: key=adda
    when: ansible_default_ipv4.address | ipaddr('172.30.0.0/16') | ipaddr('bool')
```

Comment: That means that python-netaddr is already installed to the ansible controller.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't have python-netaddr installed so I tried what  @ebal suggested and it worked. For some reason the network comparison still didn't work. I will also look at the ipaddr filter if required.

Answer (score 1):

`[0-225]` is an incorrect regex. [] Define a range of character from one to another character in the ACII table and 255 is not an ASCII character.

replace it by `(?:25[0-4]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)`

So the complete regex is :

`173\.30\.(?:25[0-4]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-4]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)`

as this post said : [Regex to match an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865817/regex-to-match-an-ip-address)

Comment: My answer seem now irrelevant to me :p.  I don't think  what you're using here can really be called regex.

Comment: I was hoping someone would post this- not only are there better ways, the regex was also wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [Jinja2 match](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html) filter to match regex:

Something like this:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    ip_not_ok: '172.31.0.1'
    ip_ok: '172.30.0.1'
  tasks:
   - debug: msg='OK'
     when: ip_ok | match('172.30')

   - debug: msg='OK'
     when: ip_not_ok | match('172.30')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this regex will not match expected ip-addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Regex isn't good tool for that.

```
from ipaddress import ip_address
import operator

def ip_check_range(ranges, s):
    return all(map(operator.contains,
        ranges,
        ip_address(s).packed
    ))

print(ip_check_range([[172], [30], range(255), range(255)], '172.30.1.2')) # => True
print(ip_check_range([[172], [30], range(255), range(255)], '172.30.1.255')) # => False
```

Alternatively, If you're on Python<3.3 and don't have `ipaddress` module:

```
def ip_check_range(ranges, s):
    ip = s.split('.')
    if len(ip) != 4:
        raise ValueError
    return all(map(operator.contains,
        ranges,
        (int(octet) for octet in ip)
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried comparing networks it work out. So I tired what @ebel suggested and it worked the way I wanted. Thanks

[image]