# Python IP to integer conversion not working as expected

Tags: python, ip-address

I am using the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590965/convert-an-ip-string-to-a-number-and-vice-versa/22272197) to convert string IP to integer. But I am not getting expected output. Specifically, the method is

```
>>> ipstr = '1.2.3.4'
>>> parts = ipstr.split('.')
>>> (int(parts[0]) << 24) + (int(parts[1]) << 16) + \
          (int(parts[2]) << 8) + int(parts[3])
```

but when I provide it the value `172.31.22.98` I get `2887718498` back. However, I expect to see value `-1407248798` as provided by Google's Guava library https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.html#fromInteger-int-

Also, I've verified that [this](http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/ipconverter.php?convert_from=-1407248798) service provides expected output but all of the answers provided by the aforementioned StackOverflow answer return `2887718498`

Note that I cannot use any third party library. So I am pretty much limited to using a hand-written code (no imports)

Comment: 2887718498 and -1407248798 represent the same number...  One is a signed, and the other an unsigned 32 bit integer, with the same value.

Comment: @StephenRauch It's the same bit pattern. But the numbers are visibly very different, due to the different interpretations of the pattern.

Comment: @DyZ, what?  Are you saying my analysis of the situation is incorrect, or just that my choice of language is not precise enough?

Comment: You choice of language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to use the library method

```
>>> from socket import inet_aton
>>> int.from_bytes(inet_aton('172.31.22.98'), byteorder="big")
2887718498
```

This is still the same result you had above

Here is one way to view it as a signed int

```
>>> from ctypes import c_long
>>> c_long(2887718498)
c_long(-1407248798)
```

To do it without imports (but why? The above is all first party CPython)

```
>>> x = 2887718498
>>> if x >= (1<<31): x-= (1<<32)
>>> x
-1407248798
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this post whilst trying to do the same as OP. Developed the below for my simple mind to understand and for someone to benefit from.

```
baseIP = '192.168.1.0'
baseIPFirstOctet = (int((baseIP).split('.')[0]))
baseIPSecondOctet = (int((baseIP).split('.')[1]))
baseIPThirdOctet = (int((baseIP).split('.')[2]))
baseIPFourthOctet = (int((baseIP).split('.')[3]))
```